# Storing a unopened database connection in a Python variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, web-deployment

I'm having trouble coming up with how to search this, so if the answer already exists, please just point me in the right direction and I will gladly delete this.

I have this in my Python code

```
db = pg_driver.connect(user     = DB_NAME,
                       password = DB_WORD,
                       host     = DB_HOST,
                       port     = DB_PORT
)
```

That all works perfectly. I'm curious though if I could put that into a global file, and then, do something like this:

```
db = global.db
# OR something like this, where the () says to actually do the opening.
db = global.db()
```

Then, just the local `db` would have the open connection, but `global.db` would just hold how what I would normally put to open the DB. The idea is that instead of having four lines, I would just have one, and if I ever changed something about how I connect to my database, I could update everything at once, instead of having to update multiple things.

However, I don't want `global.db` to hold an ever open database connection, as that could lead to issues with updating. Furthermore, I could never use good practice of opening and closing a DB just when I need it. If I were to keep my code as shown, and call `db.close()` then `global.db` would also be closed, and rendered useless for any other uses in the script.

Ideally this would be done with a macro, but Python doesn't have those from what I understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `global.py`, create a `partial` object.

```
import functools
db = functools.partial(pg_driver.connect,
                       user=DB_NAME,
                       password=DB_WORD,
                       host=DB_HOST,
                       port=DB_PORT)
```

Then, `db` is a callable object that can be used like you want.

```
import global
db = global.db()
```